# j3h081 dual interface card storage structure

Tags: smartcard, javacard

Anyone has an idea how the storage or memory of j3h081 jcop card is structured?

I want to know if it uses the blocks and sectors type of memory structure or some other structure?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misunderstanding: The mentioned card is a javacard. A javacard provides an interface with commands and responses. You have no clue, how the stuff is stored, and that is fine, since it has no relevance for you.
(Without detailed information concerning a standardized application implemented by that javacard, you will probably be unable to do something useful with it.)

The sector/block seems to refer to a MIFARE-type tag which is at the opposite end of complexity compared to a javacard; they have little in common.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. So I am developing a software that will capture biodata of applicants and store them on the card. e.g. name, dob, age, height... etc.

I know the cards come pre-personalized or initialized. How do I write the data to the card if I already have card reader with all dual interfaces capability, i.e iso7816 and iso14443a?

Does the card use a file system sort of thing for data storage?

Comment: @LemuelKnox: No, you would require a so-called *native card* (a non-javacard, but sporting a processor) to have the set of ISO 7816-4 commands available. With a javacard, there may exist similar commands, but you have to ask the applet developer for details.

Comment: so what is the way around it if I want to use a java card